# Money transfer from US account to Indian saving account while in India

Tags: money-transfer

I was in US and came back to India. I want to transfer (using xoom/transfast) from my US account(that I have not closed) to Indian saving account. Is it illegal to transfer your money back from US account to your Indian account while you are no longer staying in US?

Regards,
Biswa

Answer (score 1):

It is not ! Of course you can transfer your monies to your account in another country.
 
Its a different story if you were doing it for someone else and if the the money was not legitimate - then it would shade off into money laundering.

Comment: Just to add to happybuddha, keep a track of this. Depending on WHEN you have transfered, there CAN be a tax implication in India. There are similar questions on tax aspects you can browse to understand this.